# Umbraco - how to insert a field that has spaces in it?

Tags: c#, umbraco

I have umbraco v7.2.8

I have some template code like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="search" value=@Request.QueryString["search"]>
```

this works well to put the query string value for search string into the hidden field so when i click the submit on the surrounding form it requeries.

However, when there are spaces in the search string, Umbraco gets way to clever for itself and changes something like "red tree" to "red" tree=""

It is frustrating and seems to happen for fields as well - this must be a common enough problem.  I can URLEncode it but then when I click the submit button it gets encoded again, which obviously isn't desirable, so I basically want the following to happen

```
QueryString?Search=red+tree
```

template:  `<input type="hidden" name="search" value=@Request.QueryString["search"]>`

becomes: `<input type="hidden" name="search" value="red tree">`
NOT: `<input type="hidden" name="search" value="red" tree="">`

note that `<input type="hidden" name="search" value=@HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["search"])>` gives `<input type="hidden" name="search" value="red+tree">` which is again not what I need

Comment: Where exactly in this code is Umbraco at fault? ;-) My guess: you are missing quotation marks around the value param, which probably confuses MVC (again, nothing to do with Umbraco).

Comment: I don't understand how I can pass in "red%20tree" and then @Request.QueryString["search"] turns into "red" tree="" without blaming Umbraco a little, but the quotes around the lot as per marked answer do work even if they look wrong.

Comment: Well, you're not using any Umbraco in the code - it's all ASP.NET. By design, the @ sign isn't "intelligent" - it's basically like Response.Write in the old days, so it wouldn't try to guess where you would want quotation marks or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't Umbraco, it's the fact that you haven't enclosed your value in quotes. If you amend your code to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="search" value="@Request.QueryString["search"]">
```

It should work as you expect.

Comment: Damnit, how did I manage to make my answer a comment? ;-) Anyway, Tim and I agree entirely :-D

Comment: wow ok yes that does work, I didn't try that due to how wrong it looks with the syntax highlighting etc and lack of escaping of the quotes - that's definitely breaking new ground on something's part in terms of parsing and syntax but I can work with that now I know - cheers